# Prolog BACKWARD CHAINING INFERENCE ENGINE

Tags: prolog

The following is for university (not an assignment, rather tutorial work). I can't get help from my tutor at the moment (mid semester break) so i though i would come to you fine people to see where i have gone wrong. The plan is to create a very basic backward chaining inference engine. I did this (following the instructions provided) but now we must make a proof tree as well. Below is my code:

```
%operator rules
:- op(800, fx, if).
:- op(700, xfx, then).
:- op(300, xfy, or).
:- op(200, xfy, and).

:- op(800, fx, fact).
:- op(800, fxf, <=).

% BACKWARD CHAINING INFERENCE ENGINE with proof tree
is_true(P, P) :-
   fact P.
is_true(C, C <= ProofTreeA) :-
   if A then C, is_true(A, ProofTreeA).
is_true(P1 and P2, ProofTree1 and ProofTree2) :-
   is_true(P1), is_true(P2), ProofTree1, ProofTree2.
is_true(P1 or P2, ProofTree1) :- is_true(P1), ProofTree1.
is_true(P1 or P2, ProofTree2) :- is_true(P2), ProofTree2.

% production rules
if covering_scales then family_fish.
if covering_skin then family_mammal.
if family_mammal and size_large then species_whale.
if family_mammal and size_small then species_seal.
if family_fish and size_large then species_tuna.
if family_fish and size_small then species_sardine.
```

now after i consult the file i am to assert the following:

```
asserta(fact covering_scales).
asserta(fact size_large).
```

I am then to enter the following query:

```
is_true(species_tuna, P).
```

But all i get is the following error message:

```
uncaught exception: error(existence_error(procedure,is_true/2),top_level/0
```

My guess is that i am missing something obvious but i can't figure out what.

Comment: When I attempt to load your code into GNU Prolog, I get a few errors. For example, `is_true(C, C <= ProofTreeA)` has a syntax error. You are also calling `is_true` in your predicates, in some places, with only one argument.

Comment: also, `:- op(800, fxf, <=).` it's funny

Comment: thank you. my two errors were as CapelliC and @lurker said. Needed to have xfx (not fxf typo) and i was calling is_true with only one argument. Works fine now thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

I guess the following rules:

```
is_true(P1 and P2, ProofTree1 and ProofTree2) :-
   is_true(P1), is_true(P2), ProofTree1, ProofTree2.
is_true(P1 or P2, ProofTree1) :- is_true(P1), ProofTree1.
is_true(P1 or P2, ProofTree2) :- is_true(P2), ProofTree2.
```

Should be corrected to:

```
is_true(P1 and P2, ProofTree1 and ProofTree2) :-
   is_true(P1, ProofTree1), is_true(P2, ProofTree2).
is_true(P1 or _, ProofTree1) :- is_true(P1, ProofTree1).
is_true(_ or P2, ProofTree2) :- is_true(P2, ProofTree2).
```

With the op/3 fix, you get the following result:

```
?- asserta(fact covering_scales).
Yes
?- asserta(fact size_large).
Yes
?- is_true(species_tuna, P).
P = (species_tuna<=(family_fish<=covering_scales)and size_large) ;
No
```

You got a is_true/2 undefined error in GNU-Prolog, because the
compilation policy is there: One errorneous clause, no clauses at
all.

Bye